# Converting to ascii in C segmentation error

Tags: c, ascii

I have two nearly identical methods that convert the given char* into an ascii string. The stringToAscii method works fine but the stringToReverseAscii gives a segmentation fault 11 when it is run, regardless of if it is ran after or before the other method. I do not understand why this is happening?

Here are the methods

```
    void stringToAscii(char *s){
        char *ptr = s;
        char finalRes[256]="";

        //Go through each character in the string and append the correpsonding ASCII representaion to the final result
        while(*ptr){
             int asciiDecimal = (int)*ptr;
             int res = decimalToBinary(asciiDecimal);

             char *snum[5];
             sprintf(*snum, "%d",res);
             strcat(finalRes,*snum);

             ptr++;
         }

         //print the complete ASCII form
         printf("\nstringToAscii:: %s",finalRes);
         return;
     }

    void stringToReverseAscii(char *s){
        char *ptr = s;
        char finalRes[256]="";

        //Go through each character in the string and append the correpsonding ASCII representaion to the final result
        while(*ptr){
            int asciiDecimal = (int)*ptr;
            int res = decimalToBinary(asciiDecimal);

            char *snum2[5];
            sprintf(*snum2, "%d",res);
            strcat(finalRes,*snum2);

            ptr++;
        }
      //Reverse the temp result to get the final answer
      inplace_reverse(finalRes);

      printf("\nstringToReverseAscii:: %s",finalRes);
      return;
  }
```

Comment: `char *snum[5];`-->`char snum[5]`

Comment: sprintf(*snum, "%d",res); Does sprints allocate memory for you?

Comment: What encoding is your `char*` string if it is not ASCII?

Comment: @coderredoc I had that first but it is giving an abort trap 6 error

Comment: You can post your full code.

Comment: get rid of snum and print onto the end of finalRes directly